# No results returned when using JPA Specifications in(Collection<?>) method

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of this SQL query using Spring Data JPA Specifications:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id IN (....)
```

The two entities involved in this query have a `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationship:

ProductEntity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class ProductEntity extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    // skipped other properties for simplicity sake

    @ManyToOne
    private CategoryEntity categoryEntity;

}
```

CategoryEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
@Data
public class CategoryEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    // skipped other properties for simplicity sake

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryEntity")
    private List<ProductEntity> productEntities;

}
```

My JPA Specifications query compiles and runs without any error, but doesn't return any result:
Specification definition:

```
public static Specification<ProductEntity> inCategories(List<Long> categories) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        if (categories != null && !categories.isEmpty()) {
            final Path<CategoryEntity> category = root.get("categoryEntity");
            return category.get("id").in(categories);
        } else {
            // always-true predicate, means that no filtering would be applied
            return builder.and();
        }
    };
}
```

Client code:

```
    Page<ProductEntity> productEntityPage = productRepository.findAll(Specification
                    .where(ProductSpecifications.inCategories(filterCriteria.getCategories()))
            , pageRequest);
```

Why doesn't it work? I get results when querying the database using SQL statements, so there must be something wrong with either my JPA Specifications query or my entities mapping.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to turn on SQL debugging and search in log what exact SQL-query your JPA-query is translated to

Comment: What is your generated query?

Comment: Side note: you have [`builder.conjunction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#conjunction--) (and its opposite [`builder.disjunction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction--)) that might be more self-explanatory than `builder.and()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use join here

```
Join<ProductEntity, CategoryEntity> categoryJoin = root.join("categoryEntity");
return categoryJoin.get("id").in(categories);
```

instead of

```
Path<CategoryEntity> category = root.get("categoryEntity");
return category.get("id").in(categories);
```

since `root.get("categoryEntity").get("id");` will give you nothing as no such path (`product.categoryEntity.id`) exists in `product` table.